# Macro stuck in For Each loop when populating ListBox

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, listbox, populate

I have the following code to populate a listbox:

```
For Each cellValue In Sheet7.Range("A:A").Cells
    If cellValue.value = Get_ClientID(TextBox1.Text) Then
        equipmentName = Get_EquipmentName(Sheet7.Cells(cellValue.row, 2))
        numeroCalibracao = TextBox6.Text
        ultimacalibracao = TextBox5.Text
        ListBox1.AddItem equipmentName
        ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount, 1) = numeroCalibracao
        ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount, 2) = ultimacalibracao
    End If
Next
```

The problem is that when run, Excel becomes not responding, and not even Ctrl + Break manages to break out of the loop. It should populate the listbox according to the amount of matching entries on Sheet 7. I tried substituting `ListBox1.Listcoun` by numbers, but it still won't work. What am I missing on?

Information:

- `Get_ClientID` is a function that takes a string, and returns an integer;
- `Get_EquipmentName` is a function that takes an integer, and returns a string;
- `cell value`, `equipmentName`, `numeroCalibracao` and `ultimaCalibracao` are variables `Dim`ed in the beginning of the sub.

If more information is needed, please tell me and I'll provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your main loop, you're going through each row in column A. I suggest you set the range to `"Range("A1:A" & LastRow)` where `LastRow` is your last row, for example:

```
LastRow = Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).row
```

If it still keeps not responding, add `DoEvents` inside your loop.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I (most certainly) can say that this is not the problem. Or shouldn't be, because I have other Foreach loops that also go through the whole column, and they don't cause this.

Comment: Even if it's not the issue why would you loop through 1048576 rows?

Comment: Simply put: I hadn't bothered to cut down the range, because I'm in an early stage of developing this, so optimizations will be done shortly after (this one that you suggest, for example. xD)

Comment: This is why your excel hangs though! :)

Comment: I must admit: doing this actually solved the problem. I still don't get why, especially because of what I stated about my other Foreach loops that go through the whole column not causing this. But it solved, you helped me: I'm accepting this answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess your other loops go through an array that has set amount of elements rather than over a million rows? Anyway, glad I helped :)